# find index based on condition in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have data like this:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(
  id = 1,
  week = c( seq(1:260))
)
dt1[0:100, status := "A"][101:260, status := "B"]

dt2 <- data.table(
  id = 2,
  week = c( seq(1:260))
)
dt2[0:34, status := "A"][35:70, status := "B"][71:260, status := "A"]

dt3 <- data.table(
  id = 3,
  week = c( seq(1:260))
)
dt3[0:80, status := "A"][81:90, status := "B"][91:100, status := "A"][101:260, status := "B"]

data <- rbind(dt1,dt2,dt3)
```

I would like to find, for each unique id, the index before which a 52 week period has passed with at least 75% (39 weeks) with status=="B". I would want the following end product:

```
data_want <- data.table(
  id = c(1,3),
  week = c(153, 133)
)
```

For id 1, 52 weeks after 101 (the first row with status==B) is 153 and at least 75% of that period, status==B. And so on.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In week 153, id 1's previous 52 weeks are all `"B"`. Shouldn't the week be 138? (Similarly, id=3 should be 128?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you need (and disregard your `data_want`), then I think this works:

```r
data[, fr := frollmean(status == "B", 52, align = "right", fill = 0), by = .(id)]
data[, .SD[shift(fr >= 0.75, type = "lead"),][1,], by = id]
#       id  week status        fr
#    <num> <int> <char>     <num>
# 1:     1   138      B 0.7307692
# 2:     2    NA   <NA>        NA
# 3:     3   128      B 0.7307692
```

Verification:

```r
data[id == 1 & between(week, 130, 140),]
#        id  week status        fr
#     <num> <int> <char>     <num>
#  1:     1   130      B 0.5769231
#  2:     1   131      B 0.5961538
#  3:     1   132      B 0.6153846
#  4:     1   133      B 0.6346154
#  5:     1   134      B 0.6538462
#  6:     1   135      B 0.6730769
#  7:     1   136      B 0.6923077
#  8:     1   137      B 0.7115385
#  9:     1   138      B 0.7307692
# 10:     1   139      B 0.7500000  <-- 52-week window had 75% "B"
# 11:     1   140      B 0.7692308
```

Comment: frollapply mean is sub-efficient, why not frollmean directly?

Comment: @jangorecki good point ... because `zoo::rollapply` is my inertial go-to function, and I'm slowly incorporating more of `data.table::f*` into my habit patterns. Adjusting, thanks!

Comment: @r2evans, thank you for a nice answer. I am not sure it works though. Say I have this data: 

library(data.table)
data <- data.table(
  id = 1,
  week = c( seq(1:260))
)
data[1:5, status := "A"][6:15, status := "B"][16:19, status := "A"][20:165, status := "B"][166:nrow(dt), status := "C"] 

Applying your code, gives:

data[, fr := frollmean(status == "B", 52, align = "right", fill = 0), by = .(id)]
data_want <- data[, .SD[shift(fr >= 0.75, type = "lead"),][1,], by = id]

which is the wrong answer. It should be week 58?

Comment: Your code here references `dt` once instead of `data`. Fixing that, At row 58, the number of `B`s up through that row (for id 1) is 49, which is 0.845, well above 0.75. If we look back to row 52 (the first we can consider with a full windows of 52), we have had 43 `B`s, which is 0.827, which means it should return 51. Identifying the correct "expected output" is critical to testing and confirming a method; it helps me to copy this frame into excel and literally *count* each row; either the rules are not quite as i interpreted from your question, or something else is out of whack here.